# 高さが可変のUITextViewとUITableViewを縦に配置したい

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uitableview, uiimage

日記的なノートアプリを作っている初心者です。swift1.2で開発しています。

現在、写真付きのノートを投稿するテキストエディター機能を製作しています。
やりたいことはユーザーが写真を複数選択したときに、編集中のUITextViewの下に選んだ写真を表示することです。また、それぞれの写真の下にもUITextViewを配置し、写真のキャプションを書き込めるようにしたいです。
仕上がりとしては以下ようなfacebookの投稿画面をイメージしています。
[image]

[image: 下のスクロール]

そこで、StoryBoardでUITextViewを画面上部に配置し、その下にUIImageViewとUITextView（キャプション用）を追加したUITableViewを配置したいのですが、UITextViewは高さが可変ですし、写真が選択されるまではUITableViewも表示しません。
とりあえず、UITextViewとUITableViewを上下左右余白０で配置して、UITableViewはhiddenにしてみたのですが、高さが決まらないためかエラーになってしまいます。

このような実装の場合、どのようにstoryboardとAutoLayoutを使用すればよいのかがわかりません。どのようにすれば、上記の機能を実装できるのでしょうか。

Comment: マルチポスト https://teratail.com/questions/15640

Comment: 質問者が自身でマルチポストであることを明記するという配慮を怠った為俺の回答は削除した - http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/1770/10678

Comment: @ user10678 ご回答いただいたのに、自分の理解力不足で実装できなかったため、違ったやり方での実装はできないかと teratailでも質問させていただきました。その旨を明記せずに、大変失礼なことをして申し訳ありませんでした。以後気をつけます。